# What are the projective submodules of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ as a module over itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, abelian-groups, projective-module

Let $R$ be the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ composite and consider $R$ as a right module over itself.

I'd like to determine the projective submodules of $R$ if there are any.

First $R$ is free over itself, $\{1+n\mathbb{Z}\}$ being a base.

Now as an additive group $R$ is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups.

My doubts begin here: is it correct to infer that as a right $R$-module $R$ is the direct sum of its Sylow subgroups seen as right $R$-submodules?

If it were so then each Sylow subgroup is a projective $R$-submodule being a direct addend of a free $R$-module.

Clearly none of the former is free since it contains torsion elements.

Next question is: is there any *other* projective submodule?

If the answer is *no* then I just proved that the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is hereditary if and only if $n$ is square-free, right?

Any suggestion or critique is widely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules over $R=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are exactly the same as modules over $\mathbb{Z}$ on which $n$ acts trivially. So an abelian group on which $n$ acts trivially splits as a direct sum of abelian groups if and only if it splits as a direct sum of $R$-modules.

Comment: Following your hint I deduce that projective R-submodules of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are the (finite) internal direct sums of its Sylow-subgroups and only these, am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.